# MSAL.Net and Xamarin.Forms having problem with redirect url

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am following this guide https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2/tree/master/1-Basic

and have this code in my app.xaml.cs

```
public App()
{
    PCA = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(applicationClientId)
            .WithTenantId("tenantidhere")
            .WithRedirectUri($"msal{applicationClientId}://auth")
            .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache") // focussing on android first so ignore this one
            .Build();
    //...
}
```

I get the message that there is something wrong with the return url... and the continue button does not seem to work. I don't know if the issues are related or sepearate.

[image]

Here are my azure settings in the azure AD:
I felt that I had to switch back to the 'old experience' because the guides/tutorials etc. does not seem to reflect the current Azure UI.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have updated the value of **DataScheme** on `MsalActivity.cs` and `AndroidManifest.xml` with the correspondent clientId of your application.

Comment: I was missing the `MsalActivity.cs` file completely and had a wrong id in the manifest. Thank you, will give it a try and mark as accepted if it worked.